# Is there a way to populate user input fields with default values in thymeleaf spring?

Tags: thymeleaf

Is there a way to populate user input fields with default value in `thymeleaf`?

I understand that `th:field` replaces the `value=""` tag, but I need to populate the user inputs with default number so, that if the user does not provide input, number *0* will be passed as the input.

I cannot do this in controller as my input type needs to be number, and my model attribute is `String[] arraylist`.

```
        <input type="number" id = "a2s" name="a2" class="newMatch" value="0" min="0" max="11" th:field="*{player1score}">
        <input type="number" id = "b2s" name="b2" class="newMatch" value="0" min="0" max="11" th:field="*{player2score}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<input th:value="*{player1score != '' ? player1score : 0}" //...other attr />
```

Comment: This still leaves the values as "" empty or null.

Comment: Controller: https://pastebin.com/rnqxCUNg Java class: https://pastebin.com/AafzMZ59

Answer (score 0):

`th:field` will override `value`, `name` and `id` attributes. To ***populate*** the field you will have to use the tags separately, like so:

```
<input type="number" id = "a2s" name="a2" class="newMatch" value="0" min="0" max="11" th:name="*{player1score}" th:id="*${playerscore}">
```

Comment: Placing only th:name="*{player1score}" to the field does indeed allow me to populate the fields. but something is still wrong as this field does not send the values to the corresponding places on the next page. Also i cannot use the th:id="*${playerscore}" tag together with th:name.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using `name` and `id` html fields to replace the need for `th:field="*{myVar}"` . Like so:

```
<input type="number" class="newMatch"  value="0" min="0" max="25"  name="player1score" id="player1score" >
<input type="number" class="newMatch"  value="0" min="0" max="25"  name="player2score" id="player2score" >
```

The `th:field` tag replaces `name` , `id` and `value` fields. So one way to do this is to just use html tags instead.